# How to get responce of ajax data array in Highchart

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, highcharts

I'm trying to get json data response using ajax but I can't get result.
i will get error as follow.
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

My Simple chart data is as follow.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
$(document).ready(function() {
    var chart;
      chart = $('#container2').highcharts({

            title: {
                text: 'Monthly Average Backing',
                x: -20 //center
            },

            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                    'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Backing ($)'

                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },

            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'middle',
                borderWidth: 0
            },
            series: <?php echo json_encode($array); ?>
        });
    });

});
        </script>
```

and  i also get data array from ajax like this:

```
[{"name":"Digital Watch heart rate monitor","data":[0,0,0,180,0,0,0]}]
```

So I just want to update my chart, here's my ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "user/ajax.profile.statistics.php?action=custommap",
    data:{categoryId:categoryId,pricelowrange:pricelowrange,pricehighrange:pricehighrange,successsort:successsort,datefrom:datefrom,dateto:dateto,sortingautosuggest:sortingautosuggest,timefrom:timefrom,timeto:timeto},
                async:false,
                dataType:'json',
                cache: false,
                success: function(dataRes)
                                {
                                    **chart.series[0]**.setData(dataRes['data'],true)

                                }


            });
```

I just want my response data in chart.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: Any errors or something, what does this url : user/ajax.profile.statistics.php?action=custommap return.

Comment: @ABHISHEK:- No,its not any error. infact i also get my ajax responce. but now how to put that in success of ajax

Comment: check my answer now. This way you can access your data in callback.

Comment: You should initialise your / update your chart in the ajax callback

Answer (score 0):

Try using callback option along with the url in ajax.

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "user/ajax.profile.statistics.php?callback=",
    data:{categoryId:categoryId,pricelowrange:pricelowrange,pricehighrange:pricehighrange,successsort:successsort,datefrom:datefrom,dateto:dateto,sortingautosuggest:sortingautosuggest,timefrom:timefrom,timeto:timeto},
                async:false,
                dataType:'jsonp',
                cache: false,
                data:{data:JSON.stringify([{action:'custommap'}])},
                success: function(dataRes)
                {       alert(dataRes);
                        <?php echo json_encode($array); ?>

                }

            });
```

The following blog will help you.

[HTML-PHP wenservice](http://sanjaykumarns.blogspot.in/p/html-php-webservice-jquery-ajax.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have object inside array. So you need to access it like that for eg

```
dataRes[0]['name']
dataRes[0]['data']
```

Your code should be like this to access the data

```
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "user/ajax.profile.statistics.php?action=custommap",
    data:{categoryId:categoryId,pricelowrange:pricelowrange,pricehighrange:pricehighrange,successsort:successsort,datefrom:datefrom,dateto:dateto,sortingautosuggest:sortingautosuggest,timefrom:timefrom,timeto:timeto},
                async:false,
                dataType:'json',
                cache: false,
                success: function(dataRes)
                {      
                   console.log(dataRes[0]['name']);
                   console.log(dataRes[0]['data'])
                }

            });
```

And when you have data available you can redraw/reset Highcharts.
To redraw check api reference here:

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events

Jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/chart/events-redraw/

Comment: Digital Watch heart rate monitor
[0, 0, 0, 180, 0, 0, 0]

Comment: ok.now i get nama and data array but now how to update my chart as per data

Comment: ok thanks for anwser but its for add series i want to redraw my chart using ajax. now i get more from your anwser and i update my question please check that and help me

Comment: now i get just 1 error if it solve that its 100% working. eroor as follow.                           Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: It means you are looping over data that doesn't exist.

Comment: if(!empty($array))
{ 
             print json_encode($array);
exit;
}

Comment: if your answer will help . i definitely accepted it but as per your answer your saying about add-series but i want to set-series and redraw the chart when ajax give me response. my issue still pending. you are know about redraw-chart/set-series then please help me.